# Aligned text with dots and quotes as in the example

Tags: environments, lists, quotation

I need to write aligned text with dots and quotes(or what is it) as in examples. It looks like some kind of environment, but I don't know which(

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in several ways, but a simple tabular is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl@{}>{ . . . . . . }c}
    Lore  & Ipsum & S\\
    » & Dolor  & T\\
    » & Amet  & L\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good version. But space between words turns out to be more than necessary (here: "Lore  & Ipsum"). And how do I make a second example?

Comment: @Sergei Set  `\tabcolsep` to the length that you want (e.g., 2pt) to control the space between words.  What is the problem with the second example?  As far I see, it is even simpler, just a table with four normal centered columns (i.e.,  `{cccc}` ) and two rows.

Comment: You are my savior))) I didn't notice, that the second example is a table too. I still don't understand, why the author of this text did this... Maybe, it's a normal... I'm just starting to learn LaTeX, so sorry for so stupid questions and thank you so much!